# How to get Data from previous page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So, i have some categories. And in each category you can add posts.

But in form page for adding posts, how to get the value of that category i.e. of previous page?

This is my form:

```
<div class="container">
    {!! Form::open(['action' => 'TopicController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('title', 'Title') }}
            {{ Form::text('title', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Title of the Post']) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('desc', 'Desc') }}
            {{ Form::textarea('desc', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Description of the Post']) }}
        </div>
        {{ Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) }}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Link in category page to form:

```
<a href="/topics/create">Create New Post</a>
```

Controller:

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'desc' => 'required',
        ])
$topic = new Topic;
$topic->topic_title = $request->input('title');
$topic->topic_body = $request->input('desc');
$topic->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
$topic->save();
return redirect('/')->with('Seccess', 'Topic Created');
```

show.blade.php contains link to this form page. But to get the id of the category page that is referring to this form??

Comment: Please try to add what you tried so far.

Comment: @Camilo Check now.

Comment: You mean you're been redirected to this page and you want the id of the category that redirected you to this page?

Comment: @NorrisOduro No. For eg, In PHP category, user want to make a post. He will click on the link to this page. So, how to get the id of the previous page? So, i can store the post and display it in its relevant category.

Comment: The code here is not enough to understand what you mean. Add some code from your controllers and the previous routes

Comment: @NorrisOduro Now Check.

Comment: post the content of this route `/topics/create` and also its definition in the controller

Comment: This question is too broad. So you need to provide enough information for me to be able to help you

Comment: @NorrisOduro The form above that i has posted is /topics/create/ and the controller i above posted is controller for it to save data.

Comment: You need to add the category id to the route `topics/create` so you access the id in the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass category_id into your link as route parameter:

```
<a href="/topics/create/{{ $category_id }}">Create New Post</a>
```

Catch category_id in `/topics/create/category_id` route:

```
Route::post('/topics/create/{category}', 'TopicsController@create');
```

And then use it to create a hidden field in your form:

```
<div class="container">
    {!! Form::open(['action' => 'TopicController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
    {{ Form::hidden('category_id', $category_id) }}
    ...
</div>
```

And then in your controller:

```
...
$topic->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
$topic->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
$topic->save();
...
```

Comment: Why the route is named '/topics/create/{category}' and not '/topics/create/{category_id} ?'